# how to handle odd number of pages in pagination angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

i have a pagination code my pagination bar is showing 2 buttons right now i am facing an issue that when user goes on page number 5 it shows only single button named 5 as my data is coming inside the odd numbered pages i want my pagination bar to handle this like : page 1,2 at one time , when user clicks next it should look like page 2 ,3 at a time and in case 5 is the last page it should show me buttons like 4 ,5 and button 5 highlighted , i am getting no clue how to doo this kindly help me out ?

my pagination code:

```
<pagination page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" total-items="totalItems"
                            items-per-page="entryLimit" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" style="cursor:pointer">
                        </pagination>
```

my controller logic:

```
                          $scope.currentPage = 1;
                          $scope.maxSize = 2;
                          $scope.totalLeadItems = $scope.finalLeadData.dataval;
                          $scope.totalItems = $scope.finalLeadData.dataval.length;
                          $scope.entryLimit = 2; // items per page
                          $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);

                         $scope.search = function (item){
                          //console.log(item.LEAD_NM);
                          return !! ((angular.lowercase(item.LEAD_NM).indexOf($scope.search.LEAD || '') !== -1 || angular.lowercase(item.LEAD_MBL).indexOf($scope.search.LEAD || '') !== -1));

                            };


                          //$watch search to update pagination
                          $scope.$watch('search.LEAD', function (newVal) {
                              $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.finalLeadData.dataval, newVal);
                              $scope.totalItems = $scope.filtered.length;
                              $scope.noOfPages =  Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.entryLimit);
                              $scope.currentPage = 1;

                          }, true);
```

Comment: Where does the pagination directive come from?

Comment: its an part of angular ui bootstrap  from their i have included it into my code